# How to configure Django CMS for a second site?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have two sites and a separate page tree for each of them.

For example:

```
site_1_home
  |__ page_A
  |__ page_B

site_2_home
  |__ page_C
  |__ page_D
```

When I run site 1 and access `page_A`, the url path of that page is `/page_A/` (without `site_1_home`).

When I run site 2 and access `page_C`, the url path of that page is `/site_2_home/page_C/` (and path `/page_C/` doesn't exist)

Strangely if I go to `/site_2_home/page_C/?edit`, I get 404 error, whereas `/page_C/?edit` shows me the frontent-editing page.

How to get rid of `/site_2_home/` from the path for site 2? Is it a bug or misconfiguration?

---

I am using Django 1.5.1 and CMS 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in quite a hackish way, just by editing the database.

The `path` column in the `cms_title` table needed to be revised and "site_2_home/" had to be removed there.

If I added a new **page_E** under **site_2_home** afterwards, the path of it was `/page_E/` and `/page_E/?edit` was working well too. Problem solved.